# Why am I getting mangled menus and why can't CiviCRM find its own /ext directory?

Tags: drupal-8

My composer build D8/CiviCRM instance looks great on my local server where I built it - but then when I add it all to git and push it to a production server -> it looks like this: menus are messed up and CiviCRM is not able to find its own extension directory that it ships with.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you install D8/CiviCRM with Composer you end up with CiviCRM's `.gitignore` file in the `vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core` directory. Renaming that `.gitignore` outoftheway solves the problem. No `civicrm.settings.php` file edits required! Of course you can be more selective but think of not ignoring `bower_components` as well as the `/ext` -> that's what solved this issue instantly.